# Visual Studio messed up my .partitions File in a SSAS Project, how to fix?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssas, visual-studio-2008-db

Suddenly I can't process a SSAS project anymore. The error I get is 'x.partitions' is not valid and cannot be opened. Check the 'x.partitions' file

Last thing I remember was a checkin of the project into TFS. A good idea to fix this would be very much appreciated.

The Cube that is causing the problem is a cube with 2 linked cubes in it. (I assume it shouldn't have anything to do with it)

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at the actual partitions file? you wont be able to see in BIDS i think unless you show all files. You might have to look on disk. What about your queries for your partitions? can you get to your partitions in BIDS?

Comment: On the file system I had a look at this file, it didn't look like it had all it should in it. I could somehow work around it now by deleting the partition completely and creating a new one and manipulating the project file. I'm not sure how much a recent rename of the cube has something to do with it. One day later I got the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Either something with my solution/project is totally messed up or renaming is not a good idea with TFS and BI projects within VS2008 SP1.

Comment: yeah, it isn't an easy thing, you end up having to go into the XML for the objects and modify things

Answer (score 0):

We had a problem with a disappearing partition (the default one, no fancy stuff here) after renaming the cube. The result was that we could still deploy and process, but the database contained only dimension data, no fact data.

We noticed the .cube file had lost the Partitions node, which should be somewhere at the bottom of the code:

```
  </Dimensions>
  <Partitions />
</MeasureGroup>
```

We tried to add a new partition, which did not succeed. The .partitions file (hidden in Visual Studio) ended up almost empty. On a different machine we did a roll back, which solved the issue locally. But checking it in in TFS and getting latest version on the original machine did not carry this. We had to copy the .partitions file manually to the original machine where the rename had originated (or copy the content).

So I suspect you can solve the problem by adding the Partitions node again, BEFORE you start meddling with new partitions. After meddling you need to reconstruct the content of both files.
[SS2012, VS2012]

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, although I created it because I wanted to rename the Partition ID.
After renaming, Visual Studio showed me an error with the partition file but still showed the "partitions" tab when I viewed the cube, with outdated information.

What had happened was that Visual Studio created an empty "" tag in the *.cube file. Due to this the "partition" could not be loaded of course!

Turns out I only had to remove that empty tag from the *.cube file and voilá was able to load my partitions file again!

EDIT: I am using VS 2010 but I am pretty sure the same applies to VS 2008.